# What's the difference between kEND and $end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I got this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
```

What's the difference between kEND and $end ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In english this is stating:

syntax error, **unexpected end of file**, **expecting an end keyword**

I agree it's a fairly non-intuitive message.

**So the difference is:**

kEND = end of file

$end = end keyword

Answer (score 3):

kEND is the end of your file $end is the end tag so, something like

```
if somethingIsTrue
    puts "its true!"
end
```

Usually when this happens, you forgot to close something with an end.